# How to set timer when write exam

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

```
$duration = $this->base_decrypt($explode_DecryptValues[3]);
echo $duration;
```

Duration value is: `2:10:00` but output like this `0-410097:10:06`. 
Why are the hours like this?

This is script:

```
var TimeLimit = new Date('<?php echo date('r', $_SESSION['TIMER']) ?>');

function countdownto() {
  var date = Math.round((TimeLimit-new Date())/1000);    
  var hours = Math.floor(date/3600);   
  date = date - (hours*3600);    
  var mins = Math.floor(date/60);    
  date = date - (mins*60);    
  var secs = date;      

  if (hours<10) hours = '0'+hours;     
  if (mins<10) mins = '0'+mins;  
  if (secs<10) secs = '0'+secs;   
  if(secs=='00' && mins=='00'){
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#sub").trigger("click");
    });
    //document.getElementById('test').submit();
  }

  document.getElementById('hours').innerHTML =hours;    
  document.getElementById('min').innerHTML =mins;
  document.getElementById('sec').innerHTML =secs;
  //document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = hours+':'+mins+':'+secs;
  setTimeout("countdownto()",1000);
}
countdownto();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `echo date( 'H:i:s', strtotime( $duration ) );`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13970165)

Comment: Really and yet from what I can tell it answers the question does it not?

Comment: add as an comment